# Uninstall older versions of Mathematica

Tags: installation

I have 3 versions of Mathematica on my laptop (11.3, 12.3, 13.0). I want to uninstall the older ones without affecting the most recent: how can I do it?

I have installed also some packages such as xAct: will I have to reinstall them too?

My OS is Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: My humble advice is: unless you're really pressed for disc space, keep them all (especially 11.3) as newer versions tend to introduce lots of  bugs and it's good to have a version where any critical code can run as expected. On the question how to uninstall them, some more info like the OS etc is needed.

Comment: On Windows you can use the Add/Remove program in the control panel, on MacOs you just drag the programs to the Trash bin

Comment: It is OS dependent. As far as I know there are no official instructions from Wolfram since Mathematica did't integrate deeply into OS. I myself on linux simply delete installation folder and then edit (optional step) .Mathematica forlder (with dot in front) to get rid of some junk (be careful, since that folder contains Licensing subfolder of all installed Mathematica versions).

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, deinstall it via the App installer applet. Look at Program Folder/Wolfram Research/Mathematica and delete the older version folders.

Perhaps there are older documentations in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Wolfram Research